# When I update document it create new document in mongodb using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb, mongoose

When I update any value on frontend it get update in mongodb except boolen value . when I update boolen value on frontend it create new document for that change in collection. below is my code snippet.

```
 let threats = req.body.threat
    let threatss = []
    if (threats) {
      await Promise.all(threats.map(async (threat) => {

        threatss.push(
          {
              updateOne: {
                  filter: { "id": threat.id },
                  update: {
                    ...threat
                  },
                  upsert: true,
                  new: true
              }
          }
      )
  
    }))
  }
  ProjectThreatModel.bulkWrite(threatss);
```

Comment: Can you provide the data of `req.body.threat` when the error occurs. "When I update boolen value on frontend" is not enough information to know what the structure of `threats` is, and what could be causing the issue.

Comment: @AdamExchange basically I am converting array values into individual documents. here above in the code req.body.threat is basically array f threats which have multiples values inside..